# Rearranging hierarchy - move all <list>s (and their contents) that appear as following-siblings of an element para before the end of the para

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I need to rearrange hierarchy. Move lists (and their content) that appear after the para (as following sibling(s)), inside of the para, while retaining the rest of the data in it's current location.

**Notes:**

- The DTD allows para's to contain lists and lists can also contain para's
- The DTD is very complex and it would be difficult to write match statements for all elements that can appear in it
- There could be multiple lists following the para that need to be moved to the end of the preceding para

I am relatively new to XSL and am unsure of how to handle this being that these are currently siblings

I did not try anything yet because I was not sure how to approach this.

Thanks

Input:

```
<section>
<para updated="20240206"><para.text>This is some para text.</para.text></para>
<para updated="20240206"><para.text>This is some para text with a list following:</para.text></para>
<list updated="20240206">
    <heading>
      <name>List 1</name>
   </heading>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>1)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>2)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>3)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   </list>
<para updated="20240206"><para.text>This is some para text with a feature following:</para.text></para>
<feature><name>Feature does not move</name>
<para><para.text>Text of the feature</para.text></para></feature>
<para><para.text>This is a para with a nested list following</para.text></para>
<list updated="20240206">
   <heading>
      <name>List 2</name>
   </heading>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>1)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>2)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   <list updated="20240206">
   <heading>
      <name>List 3</name>
   </heading>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>a)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>b)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>c)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   </list>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>3)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   <table updated="20240206"><name>This table does not move</name></table>
   </list.item>
   </list>
</section>
```

Output:

```
<section>
<para updated="20240206"><para.text>This is some para text.</para.text></para>
<para updated="20240206"><para.text>This is some para text with a list following:</para.text>
<list updated="20240206">
   <heading>
      <name>List 1</name>
   </heading>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>1)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>2)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>3)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   </list>
 </para>
<para updated="20240206"><para.text>This is some para text with a feature following:</para.text></para>
<feature><name>Feature does not move</name>
<para><para.text>Text of the feature</para.text></para></feature>
<para><para.text>This is a para with a nested list following</para.text>
<list updated="20240206">
   <heading>
      <name>List 2</name>
   </heading>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>1)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>2)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text>
   <list updated="20240206">
   <heading>
      <name>List 3</name>
   </heading>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>a)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>b)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>c)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   </list.item>
   </list></para>
   </list.item>
   <list.item updated="20240206"><designator>3)</designator>
   <para><para.text>content of the list item</para.text></para>
   <table updated="20240206"><name>This table does not move</name></table>
   </list.item>
   </list>
   </para>
</section>
```

Tried the following but it is moving anything that appears after the para.

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!-- Needed to escape entities to use them in the body of the stylesheet -->
    <!ENTITY sect "&amp;sect;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <!--************************************************************************************-->
    <!--******* Stylesheet to move end para tag after list sibling                **********-->
    <!--************************************************************************************-->
    <xsl:variable name='newline'>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--================================================================-->
    <!--======= Process Root ===========================================-->
    <!--================================================================-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--================================================================-->
    <!--======= Process All Content ====================================-->
    <!--================================================================-->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--=================================================================-->
    <!--========              Get para and process          =============-->
    <!--=================================================================-->
 <xsl:template match="*[para]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::para">
            <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), subsequence(current-group(), 2)"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably best handled using sibling recursion.

When processing a section, shallow-copy it and process its first child:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="sib"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

By default, when processing a child of a section (including a list element), deal with it and process its next child:

```
<xsl:template match="section/*" mode="sib">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="sib"/>
</xsl:template>
```

When processing a para, process the following list element inside the result element, and then the following non-list element outside:

```
<xsl:template match="section/para" mode="sib">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::list]"/> mode="sib"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[not(self::list)][1]" mode="sib"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Complete code for XSLT 3.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="sib"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section/*" mode="sib">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="sib"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section/para" mode="sib">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::list]" mode="sib"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[not(self::list)][1]" mode="sib"/>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For 2.0 (or indeed 1.0) you will have to replace the xsl:mode declaration with the standard identity template rule.

Sorry this is a rather advanced topic for a beginner, but just because you're a beginner doesn't always mean you can start with easy problems!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael. I am currently working with xslt version 2.0. I apologize limited sample input but the situation is not limited to section content. I will keep this in my back pocket when we move to v 3.0. -- Chris

Comment: The use of 3.0 in this example is trivial; for 2.0 (or indeed 1.0) you can just replace the "shallow-copy" xsl:mode declaration with the standard identity template rule.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer to your simpler input sample, together with the suggestions I made in comments after you revealed some of the complexity of the input, is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:template match="*[para]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::para">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), subsequence(current-group(), 2)[self::list]"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)[not(self::list)]"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the end you will have to find some way to implement all your requirements yourself, I will show one more try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:node-index-of" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:param name="node-seq" as="node()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="pred" as="function(node()) as xs:boolean"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="(for $i in 1 to count($node-seq)
              return $i[$pred($node-seq[$i])])[1]"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[para]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para[following-sibling::*[1][self::list]]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::para[following-sibling::*[1][self::list]]">
            <xsl:variable name="tail" select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="index-of-first-non-list" select="mf:node-index-of($tail, function($el) { not($el instance of element(list)) })"/>
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), if (empty($index-of-first-non-list)) then $tail else subsequence($tail, 1, $index-of-first-non-list - 1)"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="if (empty($index-of-first-non-list)) then () else subsequence($tail, $index-of-first-non-list)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Somehow in that example XPath/XSLT 3 slipped in, an XSLT/XPath 2 version should be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:node-index-of-non-list" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:param name="node-seq" as="node()*"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="(for $i in 1 to count($node-seq)
              return $i[$node-seq[$i][self::list]])[1]"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[para]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para[following-sibling::*[1][self::list]]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::para[following-sibling::*[1][self::list]]">
            <xsl:variable name="tail" select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="index-of-first-non-list" select="mf:node-index-of-non-list($tail)"/>
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), if (empty($index-of-first-non-list)) then $tail else subsequence($tail, 1, $index-of-first-non-list - 1)"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="if (empty($index-of-first-non-list)) then () else subsequence($tail, $index-of-first-non-list)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Martin -- Thanks for the code. So far it looks like it is working. I have to get past a few production issues before I can get back to verifying the results. -- Chris

Comment: I get `<section><para>...<list>...</list></para><feature>...</feature></section>` for that sample with the code in this answer. Not sure what you consider "dropped".

Comment: Again I think my oversimplification has caused a problem. Everything looks good except when something else precedes the list after the para, then the list is moved up i.e. <para>...</para><feature>...</feature><list>...</list>. results are <para>...<list>...</list></para><feature>...</feature>. list should not be moved in this case. If a para is immediately followed one or more lists, those list(s) should be moved before the </para>. Is this even possible?

Comment: @ChrisR, I have tried to add a second XSLT sample that on the one hand uses `group-starting-with` but then tries to collect only immediately following `list` elements. I am not sure, however, this will correctly cover all your requirements, in most cases an answer on StackOverflow can only get you on your way to implement your own and complex requirements on your own.

Comment: OK. I will try to play around with it. I am getting an error on the as="function(node()) as xs:boolean" statement: Invalid sequence type: Unexpected token - "function(node()) as xs:bo"

Comment: @ChrisR, oh, sorry, I would need to check whether a function type and a function expression is supported in XSLT 2; I pretty much live in the XSLT 3 world as it is the current version and as the supported versions of e.g. Saxon on all platforms are XSLT 3 processors since 2017. I will look for an XSLT 2 workaround.

Comment: @ChrisR, I have added a version that should work with an XSLT 2 processor.